# Equivalent of Python's Walrus operator (:=) in Julia

Tags: julia, variable-assignment, python-assignment-expression

In python you can write

```py
if (n := len(a)) > 10:
    print(f"List is too long ({n} elements, expected <= 10)")
```

is there an equivalent feature in Julia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of assignment is always passed through ([because everything is an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76238070/6662425)) in julia, so you could write

```
if (n = length(a)) > 1
    println("List is too long ($(n) lements, expected <= 10)")
end
```

to avoid confusion with `==` and to make the variable local, you can use the `local` keyword. This is then equivalent to a walrus operator

```
if (local n = length(a)) > 1
    println("List is too long ($(n) lements, expected <= 10)")
end
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the above answer, python needs `:=` because python makes a distinction between statements and expressions (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statement_(computer_science)). Expressions are more flexible in where they are allowed than statements and return a value, while statements do not return values and can only be used in a more restricted set of locations.

In Julia (in the Lisp tradition), everything is an expression so you don't need a separate `:=` from the your regular `=` expression. `=` already is an expression that returns the right hand side.